# css: How to select first anchor tag inside table

Tags: css

```
 <table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="main.html">edit</a><th>
        <th><a href="main2.html">update</th>
        <th>........</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         blah blah
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here i want to select the anchor element of first th to add some styiling

I tried

```
table#table a:first-child{
    color: #888888;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
```

but failing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

### HTML:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="main.html">edit</a>
        </th>
        <th><a href="main2.html">update</a>
        </th>
        <th>........</th>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <th><a href="main.html">edit</a>
        </th>
        <th><a href="main2.html">update</a>
        </th>
        <th>........</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### CSS:

```
#table th:first-child a {
    color: red;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
```

You want to select the first `<th>` and then find `<a>`.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/MLj7e/)

Comment: Actually you should consider using `first-child` for the `a` as well, if op will have multiple `a` under one `th` than it will select both :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Very true its just that he doesn't have that so I didn't put it in there. Im sure they can work that out for themselves now they have this bit correct ;). Good point tho.